# how to install a progr. with desktop shorcut and start menu icon ''only'' for ME

Tags: windows

how to install a progr. with desktop shorcut and start menu icon ''only'' for a specific user(for me).We are 8 users and we share a VPS so if i install a program the it will appear on all users desktop & start menu too,,my question is how to install only for me?i work with windows 7 and server 2008
thank you

P.S.

my 2 vps don't have this path:  c:/users/documents and settings

Comment: Install it and remove the rights for everybody else?

Comment: install it and if they rights or not that dones't matter too much, i don't want they see the shorcut or the icon in start menu!!!